Recognizing Named Characters
I am trying to determine Special Characters - maybe hasSymbolFormQ is not the best name for my intended function in this regard:
In[29]:= (*Define the pattern for \[symbolName]*)
pattern = "\\[" ~~ LetterCharacter .. ~~ "]";

(*Function to check if a string matches the pattern*)
hasSymbolFormQ[str_String] := StringMatchQ[str, pattern]

(*Examples*)
testStrings = {"\[ForAll]", "\[Alpha]", "Alpha", "\\Alpha", "\[Alpha"};

(*Apply the function to each example*)
results = hasSymbolFormQ /@ testStrings;

(*Output the results*)
results

Expected:
{True, True, False, False, False}

Got:
{False, False, False, False, False}

And a message about unterminated unicode longname character, for \[Alpha.
How could I do this better?

If I was minded to do this I might scrape the page at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html and make myself a list of the code points for all the listed characters. Then use MemberQ or something similar.  If you haven't got a good answer by the time I come back here later I'll see what I can do, but in the meantime, knock yourself out.

The issue is that the special characters are treatef as a single character by the system (e.g. StringMatchQ["\[Alpha]", a_~~b__] is False), so you can't match it against the FullForm directly. Instead, convert the character to test to its FullForm representation first, and check that:
pattern = "\"\\[" ~~ LetterCharacter .. ~~ "]\"";

hasSymbolFormQ[str_String] := 
 StringMatchQ[ToString@FullForm@str, pattern]

testStrings = {"\[ForAll]", "\[Alpha]", "Alpha", "\\Alpha", "\[Alpha"};

hasSymbolFormQ /@ testStrings
(* {True, True, False, False, False} *)

Note the inclusion of the quotes in the pattern, these are emitted by ToString@FullForm@..., so we need to handle them.

StringLength[str] == 1? There's also PrintableASCIIQ, as in StringLength[str] == 1 && ! PrintableASCIIQ[str]. I'm not sure how precise your test needs to be, nor exactly what you're aiming at. It filters out the bad strings, though.
Try:
Pick[testStrings, StringLength[testStrings], 1]

